# Finding maximum number of concurrent users by login time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that holds login times for users:

```
 | Login time       | Logout time      | System | Username
 | 01/01/2015 09:00 | 01/01/2015 10:00 | A      | Joe
 | 01/01/2015 10:00 | 01/01/2015 11:00 | A      | Fred
 | 01/01/2015 12:00 | 01/01/2015 14:00 | B      | Tom
 | 01/01/2015 15:30 | 01/01/2015 16:00 | B      | Dick
 | 01/01/2015 09:00 | 01/01/2015 17:00 | A      | Harry
```

... and I'd like to report on the maximum number of concurrent users each `system` for a particular day: in the above example, it'd be

```
 | System | Concurrency
 |   A    |   2
 |   B    |   1
```

... because Fred and Harry were logged in to system `A` at the same time, and `B` only had one concurrent user.

I've tried:

```
SELECT t1.system,count(t1.system) 
FROM logins t1,logins t2
WHERE t1.system=t2.system
and t2.logintime <= t1.logouttime
AND  t2.logouttime>t1.logintime
group by t1.system
```

... but that doesn't seem to give me what I want. Can anyone suggest a simplest solution?

Comment: WOuldnt you want to group by system then by day?

Answer (score 2):

For any given time, you can get the number of concurrent users by adding up the number of logins on or before the time and subtracting the number of logouts.

There are several ways to approach this.  In SQL Server 2008, one relatively simple way is to use correlated subqueries.  So the following gets the cumulative values at any given time:

```
      select l.system, l.logintime,
             (select count(*)
              from logins l2
              where l2.system = l.system and l2.logintime <= l.logintime
             ) as cumeins,
             (select count(*)
              from logins l2
              where l2.system = l.system and l2.logouttime <= l.logintime
             ) as cumeouts
      from logins l
     ) l
group by l.system, cast(logintime as date);
```

To get the maximum number per day, simply do an aggregation on the above and pull out the maximum difference:

```
  select system, cast(logintime as date) as thedate,
         max(coalesce(cumeins, 0) - coalesce(cumeouts, 0)) as concurrent
  from (select l.logintime,
               (select count(*)
                from logins l2
                where l2.system = l.system and l2.logintime <= l.logintime
               ) as cumeins,
               (select count(*)
                from logins l2
                where l2.system = l.system and l2.logouttime <= l.logintime
               ) as cumeouts
        from logins l
       ) l
  group by system, cast(logintime as date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Atilla is correct about how you define concurrence. Let's say you define concurrence as being logged in with the same minute. In that case, you'd want the following (my column names may not be identical to yours as by habit I don't include spaces). If you run this against your data, it will get what you want. You need to adjust what's inside the with statement accordingly if you want to the nearest 5 minutes or the nearest millisecond (that might run pretty slowly), etc. If you really want true concurrency, you'll need a combination of correlated subqueries similar to but more complex than what Gordon Linoff suggested.

```
declare @minlogintime smalldatetime,@maxlogouttime smalldatetime
select @minlogintime=min(logintime),@maxlogouttime=max(logouttime) from logins;
with minuterange as
(
    select dt=dateadd(mi,1,@minlogintime)
    where dateadd(mi,1,@minlogintime) < @maxlogouttime
    union all 
    select dateadd(mi,1,dt)
    from minuterange
    where dateadd(mi,1,dt) < @maxlogouttime
)
select * into #tmpminutes from minuterange
option (maxrecursion 0)

--get concurrency count
select b.system,convert(varchar,b.dt,112),max(b.users)
from
(select a.system,a.dt,count(distinct a.username) as users
from
(SELECT
    t1.Username,t1.System,m.dt
FROM
    Logins t1
INNER JOIN #tmpminutes m on m.dt between t1.logintime and t1.logouttime) as a
GROUP BY
    a.System,a.dt) as b
GROUP BY
    b.System,convert(varchar,b.dt,112)

drop table #tmpminutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following for day group, see following [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d90eb/1/0)

```
SELECT System,convert(varchar(10),LoginTime,112),COUNT(*) AS CONCURRENT FROM logins
GROUP BY SYSTEM,convert(varchar(10),LoginTime,112)
```

If you want tighter window than days, you should use different group by.

This does not answer what you want fully, but you need to define your problem better. What is your window for concurrency? One hour or One day?

Following SQL gives concurrent users as you defined but without more information about concurrency window, how to to group and count this concurrent users?

```
SELECT 
l1.System,convert(varchar(10),l1.LoginTime,120) AS l1LoginDay
, l1.Username as l1Username
, l2.Username as l2Username

FROM logins l1 
INNER JOIN logins l2
ON 
l1.System = l2.System
AND convert(varchar(10),l1.LoginTime,120) = convert(varchar(10),l2.LoginTime,120)
AND l1.Username != l2.Username
WHERE
1 = 1
and l2.LoginTime <= l1.LogoutTime
AND  l2.LogoutTime>l1.LoginTime
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this doesn't get concurrency, it just gets the count of users who logged in for a given day.

Comment: This is more about how you define concurrence. If I logged in and logged out immediately? How about it. You should define minimum window for your concurrency.